# Are the following named quads (or "Geviert" in German) properly set to their unicode representations?

Tags: typography, unicode, spacing

- em space, Geviert: u+2003
- en space, Halbgeviert: u+2002
- ⅓ em space, Drittelgeviert: u+2004
- 1/4 em space, Viertelgeviert: u+2005
- 1/5 em space, Fünftelgeviert: u+2009
- 1/6 em space, Sechstelgeviert: u+2006
- 1/8 em space, Achtelgeviert: u+200a

Or should I change 1/8 em space to u+2009, thin space, and use u+200a, hair space, to stand for 1/24 em space instead, like Yukka Korpela notes about InDesign's quirk, changing my list into this?

- em space, German: Geviert: u+2003
- en space, German: Halbgeviert: u+2002
- ⅓ em space, German: Drittelgeviert: u+2004
- 1/4 em space, German: Viertelgeviert: u+2005
- 1/5 em space, German: Fünftelgeviert: u+2009
- 1/6 em space, German: Sechstelgeviert: u+2006
- 1/8 em space, German: Achtelgeviert: u+2009
- 1/24 em space, German: Vierundzwanzigstelgeviert: u+200a

I am looking for a "good enough" solution to an issue which has been bugging me for a few years now: not being able to set em spaces and typographically typical fractions of em spaces outside of specific dtp software.

I was working with the following sources for this list:

- https://infothek.rotkel.de/tastaturkuerzel/schriftzeichen/leerzeichen.html
- https://www.typolexikon.de/leerraumgevierte/
- https://jkorpela.fi/chars/spaces.html

Comment: I dont think there is a solution to your question if you dont give us context as to where you want it to work.

Comment: The context is using a so-called text expander to replace custom text input with specific snippets. In this case, making em spaces available for daily use in Windows software text input, replacing the string “(emspace)” with the Unicode character “u+2003”, for example.

Comment: doesnt sound like a design question to me.

Comment: I am not happy being led on by being asked for clarification, either.

Comment: thats fine, but its unlikely that you will get a very satisfactory answer that works in a entirely general context. Mainly vecause we cant test that context. Think of it thisway i could say nothing and than your question would just sit here. Or you can work with others to make the question such that you get an answer.

Comment: I have faith in someone being able and willing to reply with yes or no at some point in the future. These things often take time, so if anyone is interested, I am doing this: [https://github.com/mariobreskic/Beeftext-combo-settings-for-German-content-authors/blob/mariobreskic-geviert-patch/Combos.json](https://github.com/mariobreskic/Beeftext-combo-settings-for-German-content-authors/blob/mariobreskic-geviert-patch/Combos.json), creating so-called combos for the text expander software Beeftext for Windows to freely use proper German typography outside of a few programs, allowing freedom.

Comment: Well, sure however. Why does it matter that they are exactly the same across systems. Just as long as it works in your context.why does it matter that it matches indesigns implementation for example.

Comment: The idea behind typography is that it is as close as possible to being system agnostic for as many cases as possible, otherwise unicode would not exist in the first place to ensure that.

Comment: Ok, but see unicode does not make the font and the font author can override things and the type engine may override other things. So i dont see how it can be done. For gods sake people use minus hyphen instead of unicode minus or unicode hyphen.

Comment: As a graphic designer I’m sure that everyone on here is aware of the former. As for the latter, I’m interested in alleviating this pain point for everyone who wants to use proper typography. See this link for how I solved that issue: [https://mastodon.mariobreskic.de/@mario/110284022947469360](https://mastodon.mariobreskic.de/@mario/110284022947469360)

Comment: I don’t think this question is answerable unless you describe how you distinguish between a proper and improper. As I see it right now, Unicode defines, e.g., U+2004 as the “three-per-em space”. That definition is pretty clear and more or less anything Unicode does. The rest is implementation-specific.

Comment: Oh, that's easy: if another professional graphic designer would also use Hair Space as “eight per em space” in agreement with the source rotkel, then my workarounds are set properly. But if another professional graphic designer thinks that what Korpela suggests is more sound, then my workaround is improper, just like my question asks, and the second list is what they would use.

Comment: @mariobreskic: And what if you find professional graphic designers with either opinion or, even worse, a single graphic designer’s choice depends on the application, font, etc.? You seem to assume that encoding is absolute and it’s more important to have the right encoding (whatever it may be) than the right amount of space, but that’s just not how it works. It might work like that if all fonts and other software strictly adhered to Unicode specifications, but then this entire question would be unnecessary.

Comment: Then my question will have been answered beyond my simple either/or choice, and some sort of conversation might open itself up, an opportunity to understand and to deepen my knowledge, and an opportunity for shop talk, if you will, between people with a mutual interest in exploring the gaps left behind, so to speak. But it hasnʼt yet, so it remains an open question until that moment comes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of those named quads are properly mapped to Unicode characters, some are not and cannot be. There is a rather limited numberUnicode spaces that have a defined width in terms of the quad, i.e. the em unit.

You can map

- em space to U+2003 (or, equivalenty, to U+2001)
- en space to U+2002
  (or, equivalenty, to U+2000)
- 1/3 em space to U+2004
- 1/4 em space to
  U+2005
- 1/6 em space to U+2006
- 4/18 em space (i.e. 2/9 em space) to U+205F

These have widths defined in the Unicode standard. It is reasonable to expect font designers to implement that way. There is no reason to deviate from the defined widths, though designers might do so by accident.

The Unicode standard describes U+2009 THIN SPACE as “1/5 em (or sometimes 1/6 em)”. So it is not really a fixed-width space. Moreover, due to the ways thin spaces have been used in typography, font designers and software designers may have reasons to use other, generally smaller widths when implementing U+2009 either directly in a font or by turning it to software-specific spacing. For example, Adobe describes THIN SPACE as 1/8 em.

https://helpx.adobe.com/incopy/using/glyphs-special-characters.html#insert_white_space_characters

U+200A HAIR SPACE has no defined or even suggested width in the Unicode standard, just the comment that is thinner than thin space and that it the thinnest space in traditional typography. According to Adobe, it is 1/24 em. But Microsoft says that “Recommended standard setting is 1/10..1/16 of the em.”

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/develop/character-design-standards/whitespace

So 1/5 em and 1/24 em cannot be mapped to Unicode characters, and 1/8 em cannot be mapped to any single character, but you could use a sequence of four U+202F characters

Comment: I appreciate you taking time out of your life to answer my question. I wouldn't have ever anticipated to hear back from you, the man himself, but I guess server logs are not only interesting to me . I believe I will write about this on my own website, because it is remarkable in itself. Have a great retirement and greetings from Germany, on a train to Stuttgart!